# How to decrypt "Spring Security" password in grails?

Tags: grails, encryption, spring-security

I need to decrypt the password to send in email. Can anyone please guide me that how I can decrypt the "Spring Security" password in grails?

Thanks
Smac

Comment: I really hope you cannot decrypt the password (you should be using a one-way hashing algorithm), if you can decrypt the password you already have a security risk.

Comment: it depends on actual configuration, but usually there no way to 'descrypt' password. Only "brute force attack". Btw, if you just migrating from spring app to grails, and don't know how to support existing authorization, take a look at Spring Security Plugin for Grails.

Comment: You don’t send passwords in emails. If the user fogot their password, then you send them a link with a one-time token that sends them to a page where they can set a _new_ password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You should be using one way hashing algorithm for encrypting password Which can't be decrypted back. (Otherwise, its security threat for the application)

2) Text password should never be sent in emails. Infact, you should use workflow like sending the reset/forgot password link in the email.(The links can have UUId appended as a parameter for any new reset/forgot password request which is enough to identify).

Answer (score 6):

Passwords aren't encrypted, implying that they can be decrypted, they're hashed. Hashing takes various inputs and generates a fixed-length output, so the process is lossy since a large original input cannot be stored completely within a small hash output.

But that's ok for passwords. Rather than decrypting (or "de-hashing") the stored password to see if a login attempt is valid, you hash the password from the login page and compare it to the stored hash value. These two don't have to be the same, and for example when using Bcrypt they won't be the same value, but the hash algorithm implementation will have logic to determine if two hashes are equivalent.

If you store passwords in a way that the original value can be retrieved, you might as well store them in cleartext. But that's crazy since then anyone with access to that table can see them.

As was mentioned in the comments, never send cleartext passwords by email. Instead configure a workflow where your users can reset their password. The http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui plugin has this as a feature. If you don't want to use the whole plugin, feel free to steal the code for this feature. Basically the workflow is that a user requests a reset email for their username. Only ask for username, but not their email; use the one you already have. Generate a unique token and store it, and use it in the link in the email. When the user clicks the link you can validate the token and know that it wasn't just any arbitrary request from a hacker, but that it's from the user since you use their email address to verify their identity.